# Error sharing url in cyrillic

Tags: facebook, share-button

Can't share a url in cyrillic: `http://вода-серебряная.рф`. My site uses `facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php` to achieve that. The url is already transformed to punycode (`http://xn----7sbbdcmja7ed0aci5rc.xn--p1ai/`) with FB at this step.

When I click `Share Link`, an error is returned with the following message: `Could not post to Wall. The message could not be posted to this Wall`.

I've also checked the url at `developers.facebook.com/tools/debug` and it returned the following error: `Error Linting URL: An internal error occurred while linting the URL` ([see the result](https://graph.facebook.com/155637944578331)).

Is it a FB bug or how can I fix this?

Comment: Funny thing is, that _“See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL”_ seems to show the actual page content – so the scraper _can_ obviously actually read it.

Comment: Yes, the response code for the scraper is 200. But FB seems to have [an internal error](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2F%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F.%D1%80%D1%84) while linting the url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook isn't currently set up to support Internationalized domain names. If you file it at the [Bugs Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs), it'll be tracked as a feature request there.

**edit** - known issue - https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/466343236740917

Comment: So, are you stating that Facebook developers can use the bug tool for feature requests?

Comment: Not for any kind of request, but this is reasonable, since it's a URL that works generally.