# "An internal error occurred while linting the URL" - is it due to cyrillic domain?

Tags: facebook, scraper

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error sharing url in cyrillic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704841/error-sharing-url-in-cyrillic)

Facebook debugger sais: "An internal error occurred while linting the URL" for our url  [http://конкурсконцепций.рф](http://%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9.%D1%80%D1%84) (it is in cyryllic domain zone 'рф', its canonical url form is http://xn--e1agdbaatcfdnhn0a4cc.xn--p1ai/.

I'd like to know where the problem is? In cyryllic domain name or in site contents or smth else?

P.S.
[Link to debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2F%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9.%D1%80%D1%84%2Fideas%2F)

Comment: Can you give a bit more information?